# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 while compiling a C file

Tags: c

I tried to run a c file using Mac Terminal. So I put the following command in the Terminal.

`gcc main.c`

And the following message was shown.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Prior to this, I also tried to build a C project in Eclipse, but this also showed an error. It says there is one error which is `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`.

Comment: Show us the snippet of your code that says `int main()` or similar.

Comment: Also, add `-m32` to *gcc* and always add `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: it is just a simple `printf("Hello World");` statement. I don't think it has to do with the code.

Comment: You need a `main()` function. This really is a Google'able answer. It's also the first program in any C book.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does have to do with the code. The error message basically says, "Your code doesn't have a `main` function".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your program is missing the entry point (main function), you have to add this function to your code source.

```
int main(void){
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: let's presume that the OP just came form other programing language like vbscript for eg. in vbscript there is no such thing like "the entry point". and he want to learn some thing new, let's say "c language". the question is why downvoting him?.